# How to read big json?

Tags: c++, c, json, r

I receive json-files with data to be analyzed in R, for which I use the RJSONIO-package:

```
library(RJSONIO)
filename <- "Indata.json"
jFile <- fromJSON(filename)
```

When the json-files are larger than about 300MB (uncompressed), my computer starts to use the swap memory and continues the parsing (fromJSON) for hours. A 200MB-file takes only about one minute to parse.

I use R 2.14 (64bit) on Ubuntu 64bit with 16GB RAM, so I'm surprised that swapping is needed already at about 300MB of json.

What can I do to read big jsons? Is there something in the memory-settings that mess things up? I have restarted R and run only the three lines above. The json-file contain 2-3 columns with short strings, and 10-20 columns with numbers from 0 to 1000000. I.e. it is the number of rows that makes the large size (more than a million rows in the parsed data).

---

**Update:** From the comments I learned that rjson is done more in C, so I tried it. A 300MB file that with RJSONIO (according to Ubuntu System Monitor) reached 100% memory use (from 6% baseline) and went on to swapping, needed only 60% memory with package rjson and the parsing was done in reasonable time (minutes).

Comment: I don't have any experience with json files remotely that large, but you might look at the `rjson` package with identically named functions. I've heard that it can be faster than `RJSONIO`.

Comment: yes, the rjson package has more C code and thus will be faster and likely more memory efficient... although I don't have experience with it either.

Comment: Someone is not telling the truth here (where here = package `Description`). `RJSONIO` actually advertises it's speed performance: `This is an alternative to rjson package. That version was too slow for converting large R objects to JSON and is not extensible, but a very useful prototype. It is fast for parsing.`. Now, _what_ is fast for parsing - `RJSONIO` or `rjson`? Are there any performance tests out there?

Comment: Well FYI, RJSONIO works better for me? But mine is just a small json file < 1MB. rjson costs me few seconds, while RJSONIO finish in a flash. Thus, the RJSONIO description about speed performance is true for me. Also, rjson's output file is not human readable when I open it in Notepad++. Third, I really don't know why rjson can't read the output it generated back to R? My data structure is a nested list consisting of character vectors (possibly empty). In any case, I think it's pretty easy to switch back and forth for finding out the better package for your purpose.

Comment: I realize this question is old, but for those who are searching the internet, please have a look at the benchmarks posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308435/rjsonio-vs-rjson-better-tuning

Answer (score 6):

Although your question doesn't specify this detail, you may want to make sure that loading the entire JSON in memory is actually what you want.  It looks like RJSONIO is a DOM-based API.

What computation do you need to do?  Can you use a streaming parser?  An example of a SAX-like streaming parser for JSON is [yajl](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/).

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question is very old, this might be of use for someone with a similar problem.

The function `jsonlite::stream_in()` allows to define `pagesize` to set the number of lines read at a time, and a custom function that is applied to this subset in each iteration can be provided as `handler`. This allows working with very large JSON-files without reading everything into memory at the same time.

```
stream_in(con, pagesize = 5000, handler = function(x){
    # Do something with the data here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not on the memory size, but on the speed, for the quite small `iris` dataset (only 7088 bytes), the `RJSONIO` package is an order of magnitude slower than `rjson`.  Don't use the method 'R' unless you really have to!  Note the different units in the two sets of results.

```
library(rjson) # library(RJSONIO)
library(plyr)
library(microbenchmark)
x <- toJSON(iris)
(op <- microbenchmark(CJ=toJSON(iris), RJ=toJSON(iris, method='R'),
  JC=fromJSON(x), JR=fromJSON(x, method='R') ) )

# for rjson on this machine...
Unit: microseconds
  expr        min          lq     median          uq        max
1   CJ    491.470    496.5215    501.467    537.6295    561.437
2   JC    242.079    249.8860    259.562    274.5550    325.885
3   JR 167673.237 170963.4895 171784.270 172132.7540 190310.582
4   RJ    912.666    925.3390    957.250   1014.2075   1153.494

# for RJSONIO on the same machine...
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1   CJ 7.338376 7.467097 7.563563 7.639456 8.591748
2   JC 1.186369 1.234235 1.247235 1.265922 2.165260
3   JR 1.196690 1.238406 1.259552 1.278455 2.325789
4   RJ 7.353977 7.481313 7.586960 7.947347 9.364393
```

Comment: Please also check the `Unit` of the results ;)