# RJSONIO vs rjson - better tuning

Tags: r, rjsonio, rjson

**UPDATE:**

The **tl;dr** is that `RJSONIO` is no longer the faster of the two options. Rather `rjson` is now much faster.

*See the comments for additional confirmation of results*

---

I was under the impression that `RJSONIO` was supposed to be faster tha `rjson`.
However, I am getting the opposite results.

**My Question is:**

- Is there any tuning that can/should be performed to improve the results from `RJSONIO`?
  (ie, Am I overlooking something?)

Below are the comparisons using real data (where `U` is the contents of a json webpage) and then a mocked up json

```
## REAL DATA
library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(RJSONIO::fromJSON(U), rjson::fromJSON(U))

Unit: milliseconds
                  expr       min        lq    median        uq      max
1   rjson::fromJSON(U)  29.46913  30.16218  31.74999  34.11012 158.6932
2 RJSONIO::fromJSON(U) 175.11514 181.67742 186.52871 195.90646 414.6160

> microbenchmark(RJSONIO::fromJSON(U, simplify=FALSE), rjson::fromJSON(U))
Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr       min       lq    median        uq        max
1                     rjson::fromJSON(U)  27.92341  28.7430  29.60091  30.63291 1 143.9478
2 RJSONIO::fromJSON(U, simplify = FALSE) 173.30136 179.5815 183.94315 190.17245 2 328.8996
```

---

#### Example with Mock Data

*(Similar results)*

```
# MOCK DATA
U <- toJSON(list(1:10, LETTERS, letters, rnorm(20)))

microbenchmark(RJSONIO::fromJSON(U), rjson::fromJSON(U))
# Unit: microseconds
#                   expr     min       lq   median       uq      max
# 1   rjson::fromJSON(U)  94.788 100.8650 105.6035 111.0740 3457.479
# 2 RJSONIO::fromJSON(U) 520.131 527.7775 533.2715 555.2415  942.136
```

**Example 2 with `iris` dataset**

```
Iris.JSON <- toJSON(iris)

microbenchmark(RJSONIO::fromJSON(Iris.JSON), rjson::fromJSON(Iris.JSON))
# Unit: microseconds
#                           expr      min       lq   median       uq       max
# 1   rjson::fromJSON(Iris.JSON)  229.669  235.571  238.511  241.423   260.164
# 2 RJSONIO::fromJSON(Iris.JSON) 1209.607 1224.793 1232.165 1238.953 12039.772
```

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.8 stringr_0.6.1    RJSONIO_1.0-1    rjson_0.2.11

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.7.1
```

Comment: I test your benchamarking and I confirm the result(I use `simplify = FALSE` to get identical results) – What do you expect as an answer?

Comment: Can we have a full reproductible example ? Because in my settings RJSONIO is much faster than rjson.

Comment: @dicko A full workable example was included.  It may have been missed mixed in with the benchmarks.  I separated it to be more visible.  Also added session info.

Comment: @agstudy, I would have expected the results to be flipped -- ie for `RJSONIO` to have been much faster.  [This is based on what I have heard about `RJSONIO` and so I'm trying to confirm if in fact it is slower or rather that I am simply doing something incorrectly]

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I tried and it seems that you are right and I'm somewhat surprised because with the iris data I get the opposite. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216743/how-to-read-big-json

Comment: I *think* `RJSONIO` used to be faster, but now `rjson` seems to beat it. *Even with the `iris` or bigger datasets*. Maybe it's connected to some compiler settings, although `rjson` also uses the C implementation since 0.2.7 - so this performance update should have happened about a year ago, not now.

Comment: @daroczig, I'm not sure about its history, but currently `rjson` is beating `RJSONIO` on any dataset I am testing it on.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: right, we agree on this. I just wrote about the history as I've benchmarked the two package a year ago in February pretty seriously, and `RJSONIO` seemed to perform a lot better. After that I stopped following any news about the `rjson` package, which is a shame as in March (2012) it started to use the C implementation of the JSON parser - IMHO it become much faster at that time compared to `RJSONIO` that already used the C lib.

Comment: @daroczig nice and clear explanation, I think yours should have been the answer.

Comment: for anyone that finds this > 2015, I would strongly recommend `jsonlite`

Answer (score 1):

```
> library('BBmisc')
> suppressAll(lib(c('RJSONIO','rjson','jsonlite','microbenchmark')))
> U <- toJSON(list(1:10, LETTERS, letters, rnorm(20)))
> microbenchmark(
+     rjson::toJSON(U),
+     RJSONIO::toJSON(U),
+     jsonlite::toJSON(U, dataframe = "column"),
+     times = 10
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                      expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq       max neval cld
                          rjson::toJSON(U)  65.174  68.767 2002.7007  88.2675 103.151 19179.224    10   a
                        RJSONIO::toJSON(U) 299.186 304.832  482.8038 329.7210 493.683  1351.727    10   a
 jsonlite::toJSON(U, dataframe = "column") 485.985 501.381  555.4192 548.5935 587.083   708.708    10   a
```

Testing system.time()

```
> microbenchmark(
+     system.time(rjson::toJSON(U)),
+     system.time(RJSONIO::toJSON(U)),
+     system.time(jsonlite::toJSON(U, dataframe = "column")),
+     times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                                                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
                          system.time(rjson::toJSON(U)) 112.0660 115.8677 119.8426 119.8372 121.6908 132.2111    10  ab
                        system.time(RJSONIO::toJSON(U)) 115.4223 118.0262 129.2758 120.5690 148.5175 151.6874    10   b
 system.time(jsonlite::toJSON(U, dataframe = "column")) 113.2674 114.9096 118.0905 117.8401 120.9626 123.6784    10  a
```

Below are comparison of few packages. Hope these links help...

1) [New package: jsonlite. A smart(er) JSON encoder/decoder.](http://www.r-bloggers.com/new-package-jsonlite-a-smarter-json-encoderdecoder/)

2) [Improved memory usage and RJSONIO compatibility in jsonlite 0.9.15](http://www.r-bloggers.com/improved-memory-usage-and-rjsonio-compatibility-in-jsonlite-0-9-15/)

3) [A biased comparsion of JSON packages in R](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31702_9c22e3d1a0c44968a4a1f9656f1800ab.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html

Please try jsonlite its the fastest in my experience for json data especially nested

also see

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31702_9c22e3d1a0c44968a4a1f9656f1800ab.html